# How would you describe a database entity which can be an expense or a gain?

Tags: database, excel, naming-conventions

I am making software for expense management and I am describing expenses and gains as the **same database entity**. Every record or gain has a date, a description, a category and an income:

```
Item?
=====
ID
Date
Description
Category
Amount (positive or negative)
```

How can I call an item which can be an expense (negative income) or a gain (positive income)?

Does such a term exist in English?

Am I doing it wrong?

Should I keep them separate?

The software interface should look and feel just like a normal **Excel spreadsheet** (right now **is** a simple spreadsheet).

Comment: Aren't these known as debits and credits in accrual accounting? Maybe call it **debits_and_credits**.

Answer (score 0):

What you describe would point to something like a "[mixed account](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mixed%20account)" ... so if you want to show this in the entity name, I'd find something like "ExpenseMixed" appropriate